# Restlet service with multiple post resources

Tags: java, rest, restlet

I have a restlet application, apart of this i have two post service with slimier except tail of end point.

Example

> POST **/example.com/api/myservice.json** and    POST
>   **/example.com/api/myservice2.json**

I have written both resources's business in separate file .Now i have a doubt that is it possible to write both business in same file .Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to follow the way Restlet organize applications. I mean resources are attached on one or several paths. Within resources, you can define methods to serve requests, as summarize below:

- resource attached to a path

  - method `GET` (for example)
  - method `POST` (for example)

If your processing is exactly the same for two paths, you can attach the same resource class for these two paths. Something like that:

```
Router router = new Router(getContext());
router.attach("/api/myservice", MyServerResource.class);
router.attach("/api/myservice2", MyServerResource.class);
```

You can notice that the extension can be managed by the tunnel service of Restlet. See `getTunnelService().setExtensionsTunnel(true)` within the application.

**Edited**

In contrary, if you want to gather some processing into a single entity, there are two options:

- With Restlet server resources, you can't. The only possible thing is to define a class containing all your processing and reference / use it from different server resources.
- You can consider to use the JAX-RS support of Restlet. This allows to define within a same class several REST endpoints, as described below. This link could give you more details: http://restlet.com/technical-resources/restlet-framework/guide/2.2/extensions/jaxrs.

  ```
  public class MyResource {
      @POST
      @Path("/api/myservice")
      public SomeObject1 handleRequest1() {
          (...)
      }

      @POST
      @Path("/api/myservice2")
      public SomeObject2 handleRequest2() {
          (...)
      }
  }
  ```

Hope it helps you,
Thierry

Comment: /api/myservice and /api/myservice2 have different business .

Comment: both are post method ,i want to write its business in single file it self

Comment: I updated my answer with the description of this aspect... Hope it helps!

Comment: you can also consider to add your code into a business layer, instead of using the resources layer for that.

Comment: Hey Thierry! That was in fact my option #1 ;-): "define a class containing all your processing and reference / use it from different server resources". Sure this class corresponds to business layer...